# Cannot understand why div doesn't fill parent div?

Tags: html, css

I have the next html:

```
<div class="content">
        <div class="page">
        </div>
        <div class="sidebar">
        </div>
</div>
```

And css:

```
.content {
    position: relative;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 100px auto 30px auto;
}

.page {
    float: right;
    border-color: orange;
    border-style: double;
    border-width: 40px;
    border-image: url("images/bg_paper.png") 42 fill repeat;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-right: 250px;
}

.sidebar {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    background-color: red;
    width: 200px;
    min-height: 70px;
}
```

`div` with `page` class wraps by content but I need to it fills parent width except `sidebar` width. Maybe it easy but Imma noobie in CSS.

P.S. Sorry for my English.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/auzmqtav/). not sure what you want to do, maybe illustrate with a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats all you need

```
.content {
    position: relative;
}

.page {
    margin-right: 250px;
}

.sidebar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code you say content width = 90%. Of this 90 percent, you want your .page div to float right, what means that its left bound starts at 50% of 90%. You should delete the float:right and set the width of the sidebar to your wishes. Your code would look like the following:

```
.content {
position: relative;
width: 90%;
margin: 100px auto 30px auto;
}

.page {
    border-color: orange;
    border-style: double;
    border-width: 40px;
    border-image: url("images/bg_paper.png") 42 fill repeat;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-right: 250px;
}

.sidebar {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    background-color: red;
    width: 200px;
    min-height: 70px;
}
```

This should do.